# HighStock chart with two panes and using dynamic positioning

Tags: highcharts

In this demo [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume/), it shows how to make a chart with 2 panes.  However, the position values of the panes are hardcoded to work with a 500px chart.  Additionally, if you remove the navigator and scrollbar ([this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TzNrf/)), the chart no longer looks good.

I would like to define the pane heights in terms of percentages of the total yAxis height, something like this:

```
yAxis: [{
    title: {
        text: 'OHLC'
    },
    height: yAxisHeight * 0.5,
    lineWidth: 2
}, {
    title: {
        text: 'Volume'
    },
    top: yAxisHeight * 0.75,
    height: yAxisHeight * 0.25,
    offset: 0,
    lineWidth: 2
}],
```

However, I can only get the height of the yAxis after the chart is created, and then have to redraw the chart, which seems pretty inefficient.

```
var options = createMyOptions();
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(options);
var yAxisHeight = chart.yAxis[0].height;
options.yAxis[0].height = yAxisHeight * 0.5;
options.yAxis[1].top = chart.yAxis[0].top + yAxisHeight * 0.75
options.yAxis[1].height = yAxisHeight * 0.25;
chart.yAxis[0].update(options, true);
chart.yAxis[1].update(options, true);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately right now only fixed pixel values are supported.

Comment: Is there a way to get the expected yAxis height without actually creating the chart?

Comment: As I know, it's not possible.